# Simple row in bootstrap not displaying a div unless column length totals < 12

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Trying to get a login form layout working correctly and experiencing a weird issue. With the bootstrap I am using, I thought there would be 4 columns on the left, empty, and then the actual login form would take up the 8 remaining columns - when viewing on a breakpoint >= col-sm.

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div><!-- Empty 4 columns for spacing -->
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8"> <!-- actual content -->
            <div class="login-form">
                <div class="login-form-desc">
                    <h3>Login</h3>
                    <p>Enter your username and password to log on.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="login-form-btns">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                        <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;">Sign in</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p><a href="forgotpassword.aspx">Forgot your password?</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But what is happening is it seems to be ignoring the col-sm-4 and not displayed at all, and the col-sm-8 appears on the left. But if I change the col-sm-8 to say col-sm-6 (which means a total of 10) it works as expected.

Comment: I've tried your code and it works as expected. Which version of bootstrap did you used? Which browser?

Comment: Bootstrap 3.3.7 on Chrome. Testing locally (browsing to the file on hard drive)

Comment: That's strange. I checked it out on the same config. You could try remove the following row: `<div class="col-sm-4"></div><!-- Empty 4 columns for spacing -->` and apply additional class `col-sm-offset-4` to the `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8"> <!-- actual content -->`

Comment: Do you have some additional css code that may interfere with bootstrap ?

Comment: I got around this by adding &nbsp; in the div with class col-sm-4.Seems hacky